# Итераторы STL C++

Tags: stl, visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли долгое времени хранить итераторы, например, от vector так, чтобы можно была его разыменовывать в будущем и не получать ошибки (**vector iterators incompatible**).

Пытаюсь хранить итераторы `vector<char *>`в другом контейнере `vector<vector<char *>::iterator>.` Можно ли при этом удалять элементы `vector<char *>` через хранимые итераторы:

```
vector<char *> a;
vector<vector<char *>::iterator> b;
a.push_back("sasl");
a.push_back("wqe");
...
a.push_back("sasl");
for (vector<char *>::iterator i=a.begin(); i!=a.end(); i++) {
   b.push_back(i);
}
...
a.erase( *( b.begin() ) );
```

Пример может и рабочий, у меня в другой программе ошибка где-то. Просто интересно может такое быть, чтобы итераторы изменились после `erase()`, например, и вообще нормальный ли такой **код**, приемлемый, **хороший тон**?

В задаче с ошибкой использую

```
map<vector<char *>::iterator, vector<vector<char *>::iterator>> c
```

пусть есть какой нибудь

```
vector<char *>::iterator d
```

обращаюсь:

```
for (vector<vector<char*>::iterator>>::iterator it=c[d].begin(); it!=c[d].end(); it++) {
   //b из предыдущего листинга
   cout << *b[*it] << endl;
}
```

Вместо `char*` в программе с ошибкой другая структура.

Comment: Как тогда быть? Хотел просто хранить ссылки/указатели/итераторы для экономии памяти, а не плодить копии данных. Не пользоваться STL? Писать на СИ? Обычные указатели?

Comment: Расскажите, что именно вы хотите сделать. Без этого помочь вам сложно.

Comment: Думаю справлюсь, давно программированием не занимался, может как нибудь не так думаю... Короче говоря, вот решаю задачку, http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1112, несложная.
Создал структуру otr с двумя полями, начало и конец отрезка, считаю для каждого отрезка количество пересечении с другими отрезками, использую для этого контейнер map<vector<otr*>::iterator,unsigned short>, координаты хрянятся в vector<otr*>, ещё в двойном цикле запоминаю какие отрезки пересекает отрезок в контейнере map< vector<otr*>::iterator, vector<vector<otr*>::iterator> >. Некрасивый получился алгоритм...

Comment: Хотел удалять отрезки с максимальным количеством пересечении, пробовал по-другому: без удаления, добавлял в массив эти отрезки, и потом ещё двойной цикл, перебираю получившиеся массив с исходным массивом с координатами(эх...), ищу отличия, вывожу все элементы из исходного массива за исключение элементов в получившимся массиве... Вообще хочу занаво переписать весь код, использовать деревья...

Comment: Хорошо. А для чего вам здесь итераторы? Если вам нужно количество, для этого нужен просто `int`. Если вы хотите паре отрезков оставить в соответствие точку пересечения, то `map<pair<отрезок, отрезок>, точка>`. Необходимости в итераторах покамест не вижу.

Comment: @who-e: Хуже того, `map<vector<otr*>::iterator, ...>` совершенно лишённая семантики вещь. Тут ключом выступает не отрезок, как надо, а позиция этого отрезка в каком-то векторе на какой-то момент времени. Гораздо правильнее семантически `map<otr*, ...>`.

Comment: Не точка пересечения, а массив отрезков с которыми пересекается

`map<otr*,vector<otr*>>` тогда

Да уж и намудрил я, а как на счёт деревьев для решения этой задачи?
Есть ли в STL инструменты, чтобы построить дерево так, чтобы в корне элемент с максимальным кол-вом пересечении, потомки - отрезки, которые пересекает родитель. Чтобы для решения данной задачи можно было просто вывести листья этого дерева?

Comment: @who-e: Ну, у `std::map` внутри кажется красно-чёрное дерево, но можно ли им воспользоваться напрямую, я не знаю. Stackoverflow говорит, что деревьев в STL [вроде бы нету](http://stackoverflow.com/q/205945/276994), т. к. дерево можно строить (и балансировать впоследствии) миллионом различных способов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите. Итераторы должны быть короткоживущими. Причина — любая операция, изменяющая stl-контейнер, инвалидирует итераторы, указывающие на элементы этого контейнера.

*Некоторые* операции оставляют валидными *некоторые* итераторы *некоторых* типов контейнера. Например, удаление элемента из `std::vector` гарантированно не инвалидирует итераторы, указывающие на элементы до удалённого элемента. Но рассчитывать на это, особенно неявно — плохая идея: завтра предшествующий элемент станет случайно последующим, или `std::vector` поменяется на `std::map`, и вы будете гадать, кто же вам потоптался по памяти.

Просто не пользуйтесь итераторами вне контекста короткой операции.